# Generate random GeoJSON polygons

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Is there a way or tool to generate random GeoJSON polygons of specific size withing bounding box? Specifically I want to populate mongodb with a lot of random polygons and test specific functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it programmatically using the bounding box coordinates to generate the random bounding box coords for the rectangles.

For example, if your bounding box is [[100,100],[200,200]] you could do the following:

```
// generate a random width and height 
// (e.g. with random numbers between 1 and 50)
var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;

// generate a random position that allows the rectangle to fit within the bounding box walls 
// 100 is used in the calculation as 100 is the width and height of the example bounding box 
var upperX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-width)) + 1;
var upperY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-height)) + 1;
var lowerX = upperX + width;
var lowerY = upperY + height;
var bounds = [[upperX, upperY], [lowerX, lowerY]];

// create rectangle
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);

// loop through above code some chosen number of times
```